# Interop issue when exporting to Excel from VB

Tags: vb.net, office-interop, export-to-excel

I am trying to use Excel Interop to save a VB.net data table to Excel.

Using the below code, I get the error "method's type signature is not interop compatible"

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO.Directory
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ViewBillForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Initialize the objects before use
        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet
        Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim datatableMain As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

        'Assign your connection string to connection object
        connection.ConnectionString = "server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyBilling; integrated security=yes"
        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        'You can use any command select
        command.CommandText = "Select * from [dbo].[" + DaisyBillingForm.TextBox1.Text + "]"
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command

        Dim f As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        Try
            If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                'This section help you if your language is not English.
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
                Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
                Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
                Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
                oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
                oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

                Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
                Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
                Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

                'Fill data to datatable
                connection.Open()
                dataAdapter.Fill(datatableMain)
                connection.Close()

                'Export the Columns to excel file
                For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                Next

                'Export the rows to excel file
                For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 0
                    For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                        colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)

                    Next
                Next

                'Set final path
                Dim fileName As String = "\ExportedAuthors" + ".xls"
                Dim finalPath = f.SelectedPath + fileName
                Textbox1.Text = finalPath
                oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
                'Save file in final path
                oBook.SaveAs(finalPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, _
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, _
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

                'Release the objects
                ReleaseObject(oSheet)
                oBook.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
                ReleaseObject(oBook)
                oExcel.Quit()
                ReleaseObject(oExcel)
                'Some time Office application does not quit after automation: 
                'so i am calling GC.Collect method.
                GC.Collect()

                MessageBox.Show("Export done successfully!")

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal o As Object)
        Try
            While (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0)
            End While
        Catch
        Finally
            o = Nothing
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

I have done some Googling and a suggested fix was to pass the values as a String, however when I add .ToString() to the below line it hangs when I try to export.

```
oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString()
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: I went to shutdown my PC last night and it asked is I wanted to 'Save' Book8.xls. Which was strange because Excel did not appear to be open on the Desktop. I saved the file and sure enough when I opened the file it displayed the exported data. So the problems seems to be that for some reason Excel didn't open in the foreground and the Save function hasn't worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

Code worked OK for me. I used a real SQL Server and a simple table.

Try adding a Debug print to the code where you read the columns and see if you come up with some strange data types that may need attention. Step through the next For loop and see where the error occurs.

```
            'Export the Columns to excel file
            For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                Debug.Print(dc.ColumnName & ": " & dc.DataType.Name)
            Next
            Stop ' or breakpoint
```

Nice code BTW. If you copied it from another author it would be nice to post their URL for credit.